# Wordpress remote upload and add postmeta for multiple images

Tags: php, wordpress, metadata

I need to copy images from a remote server and add multiple values to custom post meta in wordpress. For example it should be like that;

```
custom_meta | 123,456,124,786,653
```

I use below code to get the files and add it to the upload folder;

```
code:1
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
$image_data = file_get_contents($thumb);
$filename = $thumb_name;
if(wp_mkdir_p($upload_dir['path']))
$file = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $filename;
else
$file = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $filename;
file_put_contents($file, $image_data);

$wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($filename, null );
$attachment = array(
'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
'post_title' => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', $filename ),
'post_content' => '',
'post_status' => 'inherit',
'guid'           => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $filename )
);

$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file, $the_post_id );
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file );
wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

code:2
add_post_meta( $the_post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id );
```

It works very well for one image file. But how can I change this code to add more than one $thumb and $attach_id for add_post_meta line?

What I am doing right now is copying the code:1 for 4 times and changing its variable names. Then I got 5 $attach_ids ($attach_id,$attach_id2,$attach_id3,$attach_id4,$attach_id5).

Then I set a variable;

```
$attach_ids = array($attach_id,$attach_id2,$attach_id3,$attach_id4,$attach_id5);
```

then change code:' to;

```
add_post_meta( $the_post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_ids );
```

and it add values to that key like;

```
a:4:{i:0;i:22695;i:1;i:22696;i:2;i:22697;i:3;i:22698;}
```

Comment: you need to add multiple featured image?

Comment: @vel no, it is another process and works well.